# How to add columns to a table between 2 other columns with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a table that gets dynamically created by the user and can have over 1000 rows. By clicking buttons the user can manipulate the table but I'm unable to figure out how to add a column to the whole table when the user clicks a button, and to make it appear where I want it to. Here's some example code.

```css
table td, table th{ border: 2px solid #0f0f0f; text-align:center; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <tbody id = "tableBody">
        <tr class = "date" ><td colspan = "2">DATE</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt2" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt2" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        
        <tr class = "date" ><td colspan = "2">DATE</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt2" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt2" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        
        <tr class = "date" ><td colspan = "2">DATE</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt2" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
        <tr class = "alt2" ><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr> 
      </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I add a column between cell1 and cell2 throughout the whole table? I thought about creating a function that gets the innerHTML of all the rows and then adds the code for another column - but that wouldn't add a cell *between* the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried creating Javascript function to add a new column on  between column1 and column2. This function should be attached on onclick event of  button.
Here's Javascript snippet for your reference:

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function insertColumn(position) {
            //Find the tr by class name: alt
            var row = document.getElementsByClassName('alt');
            for (index = 0; index < row.length; index++) {
                var cell = row[index].insertCell(position);
                cell.innerHTML = "New Column";
            }

            //Find the tr by class name: alt2. I would suggest you to use same class for the TR, where we are adding a new column
            var row = document.getElementsByClassName('alt2');
            for (index = 0; index < row.length; index++) {
                var cell = row[index].insertCell(position);
                cell.innerHTML = "New Column";

            }


        }
    </script>
```